# Jquery Jqgrid Datepicker hidden even after adjusting z-index

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, datepicker, z-index, layer

I have a grid and I have searched for quite a while trying to find a solution to make the datepicker display when the grid has cellEdit: true.  Many of the articles I found say that the z-index has to be adjusted but this hasn't worked for me.  I have tried adjusting it in the .htm head section like the code below as well as in the .css file of the jqgrid.  If I click on the cell nothing happens but if I click away on a different web page and come back the date dialog pop-up is displayed.  What is keeping it hidden even after adjusting the z-index?  Below I have put !important so this information would hopefully not be overriden.
Thanks.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .ui-datepicker { width: 17em; padding: .2em .2em 0; display: none; z-index: 2000 !important;}
    </style>

    ==================================================

 {name:'LOCK_EXPIRATION_DATE',index:'LOCK_EXPIRATION_DATE', width:80, width:90, sorttype:"date",align:'left',sortable:'true',editable:true,fixed:true, editoptions: { dataInit: function(el) { setTimeout(function() { $(el).datepicker(); }, 200); } },
    ==================================================
    onSelectRow: function(id){ if(id && id!==lastsel3){ jQuery('#list4').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel3); jQuery('#list4').jqGrid('editRow',id,true,pickdates); lastsel3=id; } },

    ==================================================

        cellEdit: true,

    ==================================================
```

Comment: are you sure that the datepicker is activated in the grid edit

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `z-index` of the datepicker in its `dataInit` function by adding the property in **datepicker** definition as. instead of directly using `$(el).datepicker();`. This will help modify the **datepicker** on initialization of the **datepicker** from **jqGrid**

```
$(el).datepicker({
    beforeShow:function(input,inst){
          setTimeout(function(){
         $(".ui-datepicker").css("z-index", 2000);}, 10); 
    }
});
```